# How to extract all texts between two specific words from a webpage and make a dataset (python)?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to do some web scraping here. Imagine I have the the following URL: https://www.lusem.lu.se/study/bachelors/economy-and-society/programme-structure

I would like to extract the name of the main program and the name and the code of all the courses a student need to pass in each semester, and I would like to make a dataset with the format (attached)

I have only tried the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "https://www.lusem.lu.se/study/bachelors/economy-and-society/programme-structure"
page = urlopen(url)
html = page.read().decode("utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup.get_text())
```

I do not know how to proceed

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO - A good first post, but one that could do with a bit more detail and the example of dataset you pointed at. The part with the code is very general and unfortunately does not show any attempt to approach your problem. It would be great if it at least showed the focus in the direction of the data to be scraped. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

this is a concept of what u want. (i think its clearing to u)
use inspect element on browser and see class names and ...

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.lusem.lu.se/study/bachelors/economy-and-society/programme-structure"
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
tbody = soup.find("tbody")
cols = []
dt = []
for tr in tbody.find_all("tr"):
    if tr.get_attribute_list('class')[0] == 'thead-dark':
        s = tr.text.strip()
        l = s.splitlines()
        cols.append(l[0])
        cols.append(l[1])
        dt.append([[],[]])
    else:
        s = tr.text.replace('\t','').strip().replace('\xa0','')
        l = s.splitlines()
        first = True
        i1 = ''
        for i in range(0,len(l)):
            if first:
                if l[i] != '':
                    i1 += l[i] + " "
                if 'Syllabi' in l[i]:
                    first = False
                    dt[-1][0].append(i1)
                    i1 = ''
            else:
                i1 += l[i] + ' '
        dt[-1][1].append(i1)
print(cols)
print(dt)
```

and this is result :

```
['Semester 1', 'Semester 2', 'Semester 3', 'Semester 4', 'Semester 5', 'Semester 6']
[[['The Rise of Europe and theAtlantic Economy (7.5 ECTS) SyllabiEOSE01 ', 'Colonialism and Economic Change inAfrica, Asia and Latin America (7.5 ECTS) Syllabi EOSEO2 ', 'Economic growth in Modern Europe, North America and the OECD Club (7.5 ECTS) Syllabi EOSE04 ', 'The Global South: Comparative Economic Development since 1945(7.5 ECTS) Syllabi EOSE03 '], ['  Microeconomic Theory with Applications(10 ECTS) Syllabi NEKA61 ', 'Financial Economics (5 ECTS) Syllabi NEKA63 ', 'Demographic Challenges (7.5 ECTS) Syllabi EOSE05 ', ' Skill Training 1: Statistics and Data (7.5 ECTS) Syllabi EOSE06 ']], [['Business and Society – a Dynamic Perspective (7.5 ECTS) Syllabi EOSE07 ', 'Skill Training 2: The Art of Writing and Reporting(7.5 ECTS) Syllabi EOSE08 ', 'Macroeconomic Theory and Economic Policy(10 ECTS) Syllabi NEKA62 ', 'International Economics (5 ECTS) Syllabi NEKA64 '], ['  Regional Development and Growth (7.5 ECTS) Syllabi EOSE09 ', 'Global Sustainability (7.5 ECTS) Syllabi EOSE10 ', 'Elective course packages 15 ECTS (two courses of 7.5 ECTS each) ', '']], [['Electives (30 ECTS): - International exchange studies, or - Internship,or - Elective courses at LUSEM/Lund University Research Design, Methods and Data Collection(15 ECTS) Syllabi EOSE11 ', 'Degree Project (15 ECTS) Syllabi EOSK12 '], ['', "The Bachelor’s thesis is the crowning achievement of the Bachelor's in Economy and Society programme. You will demonstrate the knowledge and skills you obtained by writing an academic piece on a topic covered by the programme. "]]]
```

Comment: @Neg-K sure u can text me on telegram +989397661518

Comment: @Neg-K give me your id or number

Comment: it is @negaarr.